# TypeAccessException when sorting using RIA Services and Telerik RadGridView

Tags: silverlight, telerik, wcf-ria-services, radgridview

I'm using RadGrid in a SL app using RIA services / MVVM

In my Viewmodel I have an IEnumerable collection that works fine when simply exposing the collection:

```
public IEnumerable<Orders> OrderList
    {
        get
        {
            return datacontext.Orders;
        }
    }
```

However, when I try to sort the collection before it's bound (as follows)  I get an error "Message: System.typeaccessexception  Attempt by method DynamicClass.lambda ..... " and the application hangs:

```
public IEnumerable<Orders> OrderList
    {
        get
        {
            return  datacontext.Orders.OrderBy(o=>o.OrderDate);
        }
    }
```

Can you advise how to expose the data sorted without causing this issue?

Comment: Can you paste the full exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` call to the end of your LINQ query, for example:

```
public IEnumerable<Orders> OrderList
    {
        get
        {
            return  datacontext.Orders.OrderBy(o=>o.OrderDate).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Answer could be improved if it were explained why that helps?  So why does `.ToList()` solve the problem?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I agree my answer would be better if I could explain why.  To be honest, I couldn't make much sense of the error message I got, which mentioned lambda methods and `System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable` (not `IOrderedEnumerable`).  I assume this error message is the same as what the OP got.  If you know more, you're welcome to post an alternative answer.

Comment: I don't have an "alternative", your answer is good.  I think I can guess what is happening but I thought you might have a more definitive reason.

Comment: Thanks, I tied toList() but then nothing appears in the grid?